# How to SELECT data that connect in many to many relationship table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, many-to-many

I want to select all components in material table and the equipment_name in equipment table.

[image: Relationship Table]

The equipment_name is connected with the id_material and id_equipment. 1 material can consist of many equipment name and so the equipment.

I tried to use this code in MS Access query but it said Syntax Error (missing operand).

```
SELECT material.id_material, material.part_number_material, material.material_description,material.brand, material.stock, material.um, equipment.equipment_name, material.type, material.location, material.remarks FROM equipment_list a INNER JOIN material b ON a.PKid_material = b.id_material INNER JOIN equipment c ON a.PKid_equipment = c.id_equipment;
```

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoPIz.jpg)

I am a beginner.

Comment: I suspect that you are actually using MS Access, and not MySQL.

Comment: Yes I am but I try to code in mysql language first

Comment: Then I'm out.  You need to tell us which database you are really using.

Comment: Okay im using ms access, sorry for the mistakes. i thought it has the same meaning because it said SQL lol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Access, then you need parentheses for a three way join:

```
SELECT
    m.id_material,
    m.part_number_material,
    m.material_description,
    m.brand,
    m.stock,
    m.um,
    e.equipment_name,
    m.type,
    m.location,
    m.remarks
FROM
(equipment_list el INNER JOIN material m
    ON el.PKid_material = m.id_material)
INNER JOIN equipment e
    ON el.PKid_equipment = e.id_equipment;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The bad news is when I try the codes it shows none of the value and the good news is i got no error. Why does it happen?

Comment: Well maybe the problem is with your source data.  I answered mainly to fix the syntax errors.  You should show example data if you need help with the business logic of the query.

Comment: Based on your sample data, you should be getting some rows back in the result set.  I'm not sure why the above query is turning up empty.